# F-Droid release fails. ERROR: No signing certificates found in repo

Tags: android, apk, fdroid

On the F-Droid server, I drop the apk in fdroid/repo folder and run `fdroid udpate -c` but I get: `ERROR: No signing certificates found in repo/MyApp.apk` and `WARNING: Skipping 'MyApp.apk' with invalid signature!`

Answer (score 0):

When building the apk,

- Select `Generate Signed Bundle / APK...`
- Select APK.
- Select Keystore path, alias, password.
- **uncheck V2**

[image]